# RSpec and object constructor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a singleton class, let's call it `NamesList`:

```
class NamesList
  include Singleton

  def initialize
    if names_cached?
      output_names
    else
      cache_names
    end 
  end

  ...

  private

  def cache_names
    Rails.cache.write('some_names_list', NamesClass.some_scope)
  end
end
```

In my spec, I would like to test that when cache is set - getting the instance won't issue a DB connection. My spec:

```
it "doesn't call database if cache is set" do
  Rails.cache.exist?('some_names_list', :whatever)
  expect(NamesClass).to receive(:some_scope)
  NamesList.instance
end
```

It doesn't work. However, if I move contents of `initialize` method into some other method (say, `.some_method`), so when I do `NamesList.instance.some_method` - my test passes. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, yay to me! Found a solution already:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14366444/1870446

Should've just did `ActiveRecord::Base.should_not_receive(:establish_connection)`